# Npgsql will not process pgp_sym_decrypt query - works from command line

Tags: postgresql, encryption, npgsql

I have a column defined as bytea in a table which has been encrypted using a hex encoded password.

I can read the data out from putty as follows:

```
SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(_encypted_text, E'\\x465af9b6f0ea0207188236e8698c76772f4fedcbc39fabf29c2c4d98b23d4e72') FROM msg;
 pgp_sym_decrypt
------------------
 This is the text
(1 row)
```

However when I use Npgsql to run the same query it throws an exception :

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: 39000: Wrong key or corrupt data
```

The code I am using is

```
        // create new connection
        con = new NpgsqlConnection(m_ConnectString);

        // setup certificate handler
        con.UserCertificateValidationCallback = theUserCertificateValidationCallback;

        // setup query string
        strQuery = "SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt(_encypted_text, E'\\x465af9b6f0ea0207188236e8698c76772f4fedcbc39fabf29c2c4d98b23d4e72') FROM msg ";

        // create a new comnmand using the query and connection
        cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strQuery, con);

        // open the connection
        con.Open();

        // execute the query
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The last line trips the Exception handler.

Any ideas why the two interfaces are behaving differently ?
How can I decrypt via Npgsql?

Answer (score 1):

I worked out that there may be a second level of parsing going on with the query having to pass via the API.  Therefore a second set of escape chars were needed.

The password needed to start with

```
E'\\\\x
```

rather than

```
E'\\x
```

when used via the API